# select checkboxes inside div from class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am new to programming.
Please help me.

My Html is  like :

```
<div class = "myclass"> 
    <div>
        <div> 
            <input type="checkbox" id="as" value="11" text="onerr"/>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Checkbox1" value="12" text="twowo"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to loop all the checkbox inside the div of class "myclass"

i did

```
 $(".myclass input[type:checkbox]").each(function (ii) {

        //here my code

        });
```

but it gives js error

what i did wrong please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `type="checkbox"` in place of `type:checkbox` like

```
$(".myclass input[type='checkbox']").each(function (ii) {
    // your code
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mUncb/)

You can use [:checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) like,

```
$(".myclass input:checkbox").each(function (ii) {
     console.log(this.value);
});
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mUncb/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Use :checkbox like this

```
$('.myclass input:checkbox')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".myclass input:checkbox").each(function (ii) {
    //here my code
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
$(".myclass input[type='checkbox']").each(function (ii) {
    // your code
});
```

even this will work

```
$('.myclass input:checkbox').each(function (ii) {
    // your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is here : 
To select `checkbox`, you can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this

```
$(".myclass input[type=checkbox]").each(function (ii) {

$(".myclass input[type='checkbox']").each(function (ii) {//quotes optionals but use them if there is some special chars
```

OR [:checkbox selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)

```
$(".myclass input:checkbox").each(function (ii) {

$(".myclass :checkbox").each(function (ii) {//is identical
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this using the [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selector:-

```
$(".myclass input:checkbox").each(function (e) {....
```

---

You got the error in your code below:-

```
$(".myclass input[type:checkbox]").each(function (ii) {
                   ___^___
```

because of the error in the above place.

The correct syntax for that based on [`Attribute Equals`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) selector is:-

```
$(".myclass input[type=checkbox]").each(function (ii) {
```